# angular-ui-router not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have index.html which i am able to load but angular-ui-router is not routing it to proper templateURl (app.html is in same deirectoy as of index.html).I have added all the required script but it is not working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app ="mustReadAlgo">
    <head>
        <title>AngularJS Basic Example</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/animate.min.css" />
        <script type='text/javascript' src="public/lib/moment.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="../../public/lib/lodash.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="../../public/lib/angular/angular.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>


        <script type='text/javascript' src="../../public/lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="../../public/lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="../../app.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="../../app/controllers/app.controller.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>





    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container" ui-view="" ></div>


    </body>
</html>
```

And my app.js is

```
    'use-strict';

    angular.module('mustReadAlgo',['ui.router']).config($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        $stateProvider.state('home',{

            url :'/',
            templateUrl : 'app.html',(is in same directory as of index.html)
            controller :'mustReadAlgoCntrller'


        });



    }).run(function(){


    });
```

And controller code is in app.controller.js

```
angular.module('mustReadAlgo').controller('mustReadAlgoCntrller',function($scope)
{
    $scope.message='Hello World';
    console.log('inside controller');
});
```

Content of app.html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <button class="form-control btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>Hello World</button>
  </div>
    <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

But ui routing is not working properly to load the templateUrl?
Can anyone please help me out i am new to angular js .

Comment: That doesn't look like a URL.

Comment: Yea ,but it should work it is a html code so it should dispaly that.Even if i am using any url there it is not working.Say if i add template Url as 'app.html' which is at the same location where index.html is.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Maybe a typo in 'mustReadAlgoCntrller'?

Comment: Thanks for help .I dont see nay errors  i checked that  there is no typo.Adding controller code too in edit.

Comment: Why are you including both the regular and minimized versions of `angular.ui.router.js`? Also, maybe show the contents of `app.html`.

Comment: Added app.html content .And no luck with removing the minimized verison of angular.ui.router.js

Comment: why are you loading ui router twice? You're including the minified and unminified version

Comment: Thanks for help. I removed unminified one but no luck.

Comment: put a `console.log()` in your config to make sure it is running. Nothing is standing out to me. You are sure the error console has nothing? What about the network tab? Are there any 404s?

Comment: Thanks againg for helping out . It is not even hitting the config.I cant see any log meesage

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
<div class="container">
   <ui-view></ui-view>
</div>
```

// instead of:

```
<div class="container" ui-view="" ></div>
```

Comment: At the definition of the view directive in the source code you can read restrict: 'ECA'. In the documentation is a reference for <ui-view/> when using abstract views.

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing straight HTML to use as the template you need to use `template:`, not `templateUrl:`. [Here are the docs on templates](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#templates).

Comment: Thanks ,I will try that .Sorry i edited the question to use templateUrl.

Comment: I tried it with template to but that is not working as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a state for otherwise in the state configuration and the use the statename in the $urlRouterProvider.otherwise function

```
$stateProvider
    .state("otherwise", { url : '/'})

 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/otherwise');
```

Answer (score 0):

Inject $state in controller, that would solve the problem.
To make it clearer-

```
    angular.module('mustReadAlgo', ['ui.router']).controller('mustReadAlgoCntrller',['$scope', '$state', function($scope, $state)
{
    $scope.message='Hello World';
    console.log('inside controller');
}]);
```

Comment: How will this help resolve the issue? The OP is not using `$state` within the `mustReadAlgoCntrller` controller.